# String Parsing Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I convert this following dataframe to the following expected output?

**DataFrame:**

```
col_A
A => B
B => C
D => F
```

**Output:**

```
col_A  col_B  col_C
A      =>     B
B      =>     C
D      =>     F
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `separate` with one or more space (`\\s+`) as the `sep`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   separate(col_A, into = c("col_A", "col_B", "col_C"), sep = "\\s+")
```

-output

```
   col_A col_B col_C
1     A    =>     B
2     B    =>     C
3     D    =>     F
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col_A = c("A => B", "B => C", "D => F")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using basic syntax, you could use:

```
col_A <- c('A => B','B => C','D => F')
df <- data.frame(strsplit(col_A, split = ' '))
names(df) <- paste0('col_',LETTERS[1:3])
df
  col_A col_B col_C
1     A     B     D
2    =>    =>    =>
3     B     C     F
```